# Finding the local maximum of piecewise cubic function in R

Tags: r, maximization

I have picewise cubic function and I want to find all the local maxima of it, how can I find all peaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to find the maximum numerically using `optimize`.  First you have to write the actual function:

```
x <- c(0.014, 0.034, 0.059, 0.061, 0.069, 0.080, 0.123, 0.142, 0.165, 
   0.210, 0.381, 0.464, 0.479, 0.556, 0.574, 0.839, 0.917, 1.649, 1.702, 
   1.893, 1.932 ,2.337, 2.628, 4.510, 4.584, 5.267, 5.299)
f<-function(z){
    z1<-pmax(0,z-x)
    sum(z1^2-(z^3-z1^3)/3)
}
```

Then:

```
> optimize(f,c(0,5),maximum=T)
$maximum
[1] 2.22133

$objective
[1] 8.486057
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find all local maxima if we have more than one local maximum ?

Comment: :I  got this result with your code:> optimize(f,c(0,5),maximum=T)
$minimum
[1] 4.999922

$objective
[1] -46.54533

Warning message:
In if (maximum) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. How did you get the maximum?

Comment: To find more local maxima, briefly, the strategy would to find the first local maximum, then find the next local minimum after that, then the next local maximum, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a way to do this with regular expressions, and there are probably better ways to find all local maxima of a cubic function, but this works pretty well.  It will also take into account repeated values and boundary conditions.

```
vals=f(x)

text=paste0(substr(format(diff(vals),scientific=TRUE),1,1),collapse="")
sort(na.omit(c(gregexpr('[ ][0]*-',text)[[1]]+1,ifelse(grepl('^-',text),1,NA),
 ifelse(grepl('[^-]$',text),length(vals),NA))))
```

Comment: We have a function of z not x, how can I get the local maxima with your code?

Comment: x is just whatever you want to plug in.  It doesn't matter what variable you name the parameter it's passed to.  All you need to do is assign x, define f(z) (or f(x), f(q), f(llama), etc.), and then run the code.  It should handle every case for finite values.